# Dependencies when using Jupyter with Poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, python-poetry

I'm taking courses that require me to use the jupyter notebook format and determined that it's a good time to start using Poetry for reproducibility later on.
I don't want to come back to a notebook that used to work and have it fail because of a package having been updated.

The problem is that I don't actually know what is the minimum required for actually running the notebook, and thus what the actual direct dependencies are (before I add numpy and other packages that I actually use directly).

I searched for examples of people using jupyter and poetry in the same project.
However most where pretty old and had wild inconsistencies, some with jupyter as direct dependency, others with it as a development one, some without it at all expecting it to just be part of the environment.

I know that jupyterlab should be a development dependency.
However I do not know what package(s) I should include as direct dependencies.
What is the consensus on this (if there is one) in the community?

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I don't want to come back to a notebook that used to work and have it fail because of a package having been updated." It seems you may be conflating environment management with Python packaging and dependency management. For what I quoted from your post, the main tools used are pip and conda. See [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/reproducibility.html#pin-dependencies) for how they are used in conjunction with MyBinder. You can use similar approaches yourself.  Docker can also be a way to containerize your project environment.

Comment: Poetry is more for making code projects that would get distributed as packages. Those packages that would be used via imports in Jupyter notebooks or Python scripts. Or run using `%run` in notebooks or using `python` on the command line. If you use `pip list`, `conda list`, and watermark in your notebooks or in a notebook shared in the project folder within your other notebooks in that project, example [here](https://github.com/fomightez/bendit-binder/tree/master/details_on_versions_noted_when_all_working), you'll know what versions you were calling in your notebook and can later get those ...

Comment: <continued> matching versions of projects packages/modules. Some of those projects will probably have been developed using Poetry or Flit to manage the packaging & publishing to PyPI (the Python Package Index). Jupyter itself is hopefully mostly agnostic to specific version. With '**mostly**' doing a lot of heavy lifting here as with complex output you do get bugs that are particular to the Jupyter interface/version. Mainly though the behavior and results in Jupyter (with Python-backed kernel) & if you were running the Python code directly with Python should be very close to same

Comment: In the future, posts such as this would be best as a post at [the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). StackOveflow isn't meant for topics of general advice and recommendations, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Wayne I'm not using conda at all, I'm using pip directly. Yes, for full reproducibility running everything inside of a Docker container would be ideal, however what I really want is to have a good core set of both dev a direct dependencies to that I could start from each time.

Comment: Sure. I didn't mean to imply you had to use conda. It's best to stick with one as much as possible. Mixing-and-matching can lead to headaches.

Comment: [Here is an open source example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/blockchain-stackoverflow) of Poetry-distributed Jupyter environment with very fresh versions. I would say, for research work piece it's irrelevant if you add dependencies as dev or normal and it won't matter in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

Note that my answer will be oriented to the Poetry version current at time of writing which is Poetry 1.6.x

To add Jupyter as a dev dependency your desired incantation is

`poetry add notebook --group dev`

There is no need to add jupyter lab explicitly as a dependency as notebook will include it.

Jupyter will be scoped to the confines of the virtual environment that Poetry has set up for your project so in order to run jupyter (lab) you'll need to use the `poetry run` command like so

`poetry run jupyter lab`

And this will spin up a jupyter lab instance that'll open up in your browser as you're likely accustomed to.

> However I do not know what package(s) I should include as direct dependencies. What is the consensus on this (if there is one) in the community?

Having installed jupyter within your project's poetry environment, your jupyter lab instance will only be able to "see" other libraries/packages that are also installed in that same environment. So you'll want to add whatever dependencies are necessary to support whatever you're trying to accomplish.

For instance, if you want to work with pytorch or hugging face models you'll need to add them to your poetry project before you can import them in jupyter. Also, keep in mind that you have to add dependencies *before* you launch your jupyter instance (re-launch jupyter if you add a dependency after the fact).

`poetry add torch transformers`

Whether you add them as main dependencies vs. dev dependencies will be governed by whether they support the workflow or work "product". If you're experimenting with ML models than the outputs or products of your work are likely ML models and so the libraries you use to define and use them are necessary for you or anyone else to consume your work. Jupyter (notebook UI), pytest (testing), mypy (typechecking), ruff (linting/formatting), and other things that are part of your workflow but not involved in defining or using your products would not.

For an analogy, if you're serving food at a restaurant, you provide your diners with the plates, utensils, napkins, etc. they need to eat the food you've produced. You do not provide them with the stove, oven, pots, or pans you used to make it.

In an educational setting, you may not be producing work to be consumed or distributed by anyone but yourself; so to some degree the main vs. dev distinction may only be theoretical, but it's never a bad time to hone good habits :)